# Image of a union under a bijective restriction

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

There's a result that seems obvious that I'm having a hard time formally proving. Let $f: X \to Y$, $A, C \subset X$, and $B \subset Y$ and suppose $f|_A: A \to B$ is a bijection. Then it should be the case that $f(C \cap A) = f(C) \cap B$ (Munkres uses this fact in his explanation that covering maps are open, for example). This seems obviously true, but I can't figure out how to formally show that, for $b \in B$, if $b \in f(C)$, then $b \in f(C \cap A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true with additional assumptions.  For instance, let $X=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=Y=\{1,2\}$, $f(x)=\min(x,2)$, $A=\{1,2\}$, and $C=\{1,3\}$.  Then $f(C\cap A)=\{1\}$ but $f(C)\cap B=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: I just realised that I misread Munkres' discussion and concluded that I was probably wrong, as well. Thanks for saving my sanity.

Comment: +1 Re clarifying that $f|_{A}$ being a bijection does not imply that $f(C \cap A) = f(C) \cap f(A).$